# Multiple tags using act as taggable on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, tags, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Post with array

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
Months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
end
```

Also I have a view file edit.html.erb with following string:

```
<%= f.select :tag_list, Post::Months, { }, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => "form-control", :style => "width:450px;" } %>
```

When I use this code I can't add or update post tags, the error in console is: `Unpermitted parameters: tag_list` maybe it's cause i send an array of tags?

But if I use single select : `<%= f.select :tag_list, Post::Months %>` everything works fine.
How I can add more then one tag to Post and why it works in 2 case but doesn't at first if I am using the same array.

Comment: Do you have :tag_list in your post_params?

Comment: yes params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :thumbnail, :data, :tag_list)

Comment: Michael Szyndel, Thanks! It was that, solved my issue